# I've some problems doing many http request into loop

Tags: angular, loops, while-loop, httprequest

I try to get elements from my back-end to generate a nav. To be more specific I've some equipment's group. Theses one are related to sub-nav items. Theses sub-nav items are potentially related to sub-nav items and the last sub-nav is related to a global nav item. So for each group I try to get all sub-nav related and the global one. I've initially the list of group. I loop on it to get the sub-nav items directly related to this group, then I store the attribute related to the other sub-nav. Then I use "while" instruction to get all sub-nav items while the attribute isn't null. If It's null there is no more sub-nav item. But I think there is an async problem and I don't know how to solve it. request inside while instruction doesn't stop. It does the same request to infinity

```js
        idParent = null;
        constructor(private sousMenuService: SousMenuService, private groupeService: GroupeService, private userService: UserService, private supportService: SupportService) { }

        ngOnInit() {
                console.log(this.role_user);
                this.loading = true;


                //Récupération des informations de l'équipe de l'utilisateur - 
                this.supportService.getSupportById(this.id_support).subscribe(support =>{
                this.support = support[0];
                console.log(this.support.acces);

                //!!!this.access is a tab of string with only the name of group(it's used to get group that have link with sub-nav)!!!

                this.acces = this.support.acces.split(';');


                //Récupération des groupes d'équipements accessibles par le support de l'utilisateur ( en bouclant sur chaque groupe d'équipement)
                for (var i= 0; i < this.acces.length; i++){
                        console.log('itération',i);
                        //this.parent = true;
                        this.groupeService.getGroupeByName(this.acces[i]).subscribe(grp =>{
                        console.log(i); //this console.log show me 5 for each iteration (bc of the async)

                        //Récupération des menus liés directement aux groupes d'équipements
                                this.sousMenuService.getSousMenuById(grp[0].id_menu).subscribe(resSm => {
                                //      this.sousMenu.push(resSm[0]);
                                console.log('le sous menu ',resSm[0].id_parent);
                                this.idParent = resSm[0].id_parent;

//
All console.log inside while don't show anything I can just see that there are several requests looping
                                                while(this.idParent!= null){
                                                //      if (this.idParent == null){
                                                //      this.parent = false;
                                                //      console.log('pas de parent');
                                                //      }
                                        //Récupération des menus parents
                                                this.sousMenuService.getSousMenuById(this.idParent).subscribe(sousMenu2=>{
                                                console.log('bonjour');
                                                this.idParent = sousMenu2[0].id_parent;
                                                console.log(sousMenu2[0].id_parent);
                                                //if (this.idParent == null)
                                                //console.log('voila');
                                        });
                                        }
                                });
                        });

                }
                console.log(this.grps);
                console.log(this.sousMenu);
        });
}
```

I want to switch correctly idParent and get right result. Any suggestions ? Thanks guys

Comment: Never do nested subscriptions - NEVER! Use higher level operators like switchMap or use async-await. Also you really should unsubscribe when you subscribe.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm You don't have to unsubscribe from API subscription as it's done automatically by HttpClient. Regarding the nested subscriptions, those can be used in this context (Api calls)

Comment: I Don't know how to use switchMap or async-await. I'm redoing the process to see where it fails. the problem is in the while instruction. Does someone know how to get this while instruction asyncronous ?